# Google Tag Manager pushing unique values to Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

On my page I currently have 3 tags setup through Google Tag Manager. They are as follows:

1. Tag for people who clicked X
2. Tag for people who clicked Y
3. Tag for page views

In Google Analytics, the calculated metric I would like to get is anyone who clicked **either** X or Y divided by page views. Currently I use a calculated metric that says (1 + 2)/3 but found that it doesn't work as some users clicked both 1 and 2 thus distorting my metric. (ie. regardless of whether users clicked 1 or 2, I would still like to count it as one count). I am unable to include the 1 and 2 within the same tags cause they reside in different classes and so on.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather thank looking at the count of events, have you tried looking at the count of sessions containing the events? You could then take the count of sessions containing an x or y event and then divide that by 3.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for the reply. But how exactly does one count a session containing an X or Y event? I can't include them in one tag in Google Tag Manager because they reside in different classes and so on. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Fire, you'll want to start by creating a segment in GA that includes sessions where event category/label/action (whichever contains x and y) exactly matches X OR Y (see [screenshot](https://snag.gy/MWceRz.jpg)).  Once that segment is created, you can use it in your custom metric and divide it by 3.

Comment: Thank you for your help Norman. I am currently traveling and would try it out soon.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to count one click I suggested you solve this not within GA (which I think would be difficult), but with a bit of code; when a user clicks either of the buttons set a javascript variable (e.g. window.buttonclick=true) and use that in a blocking trigger for your event tag. That way you would only catch the first event per page (which, if I understand correctly, is more or less what you want) and your metric isn't incremented twice.

Comment: This would work IF the asker wants to count more than one event for the user session in the event that the user would decide to refresh the page.  My understanding of the question is that the asker ONLY wants to know if the user clicked either X or Y in the session rather than for the page view.